# rename a duplicated IDs pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I think it is stupid question but couldn't think of the answer d:

I have a family ID which is duplicated for all family members, it looks like:

| Fam_ID | member_no |
| --- | --- |
| 12121 | 1 |
| 12121 | 2 |
| 12121 | 3 |
| 12121 | 4 |
| 12121 | 5 |
| 12121 | 6 |
| 12121 | 7 |
| 12121 | 8 |
| 12124 | 1 |
| 12124 | 2 |
| 12125 | 1 |
| 12125 | 2 |
| 12125 | 3 |

what i want is renameing the family ID, whether by numbering or labeling with family1,family2 ....
and results will be:

| Fam_ID | member_no | fmily_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12121 | 1 | family1 |
| 12121 | 2 | family1 |
| 12121 | 3 | family1 |
| 12121 | 4 | family1 |
| 12121 | 5 | family1 |
| 12121 | 6 | family1 |
| 12121 | 7 | family1 |
| 12121 | 8 | family1 |
| 12124 | 1 | family2 |
| 12124 | 2 | family2 |
| 12125 | 1 | family3 |
| 12125 | 2 | family3 |
| 12125 | 3 | family3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
for ix, fam in enumerate(df.Fam_ID.unique()):
    df.loc[df.Fam_ID==fam, 'fmily_label'] = f'family{ix+1}'
```